# Can somebody assist me in centering and aligning the Author part in Latex?

Tags: latex

[image: I must center the author and supervisor parts and align them.]

```
    { \huge Design and Development of a School Data Management System}\\[0.4cm]
\vspace{1 cm}

\begin{minipage}{0.8\textwidth}
\begin{flushleft} \large
\emph{Author:}\\  
Ray \textsc{L}
\end{flushleft}

\begin{flushright} \large
\emph{Supervisor:} \\
Ing.Y \textsc{Chouiref}
\end{flushright}
\end{minipage}\\[5cm]

\large{2022-2023}\\[2cm]

\end{titlepage}
```

tried the block above, but he thought they were two separate parts, so he arranged them after one another. Can you give me any tips to get them on the same line and in the middle?

Comment: Don't post pictures of code. Nobody wants to retype all the code before being able to start working on an answer. Please read [mre] instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `minipage`s to place two text blocks besides each other:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\begin{minipage}{.5\textwidth}
\raggedright\large
\emph{Author:}
  
Ray \textsc{L}

\end{minipage}%
\begin{minipage}{.5\textwidth} 
\raggedleft\large
\emph{Supervisor:}

Ing.Y \textsc{Chouiref}

\end{minipage}%

\end{document}
```

Off-topic:

- don't abuse `\\` for line breaks. One really shouldn't use this outside of tables etc. If you want to start a new paragraph, just leave an empty line
- if you change the font size, you must end the current pararaph before you switch back to the normal size. Otherwise all your line spacing in wrong. You can see this in how the two lines of your title nearly touch each other.
- commands like `\large` are switches and don't take an argument. Don't write `\large{...}`, use `{\large ....}` instead